# How to update Web Application directory with "appcfg update" command on a MAC?

Tags: bash, google-app-engine, netbeans, terminal, netbeans-8

I am developing a Web Application using NetBeans IDE on MAC OS and want to deploy it using Google App Engine. Before deploying, we have to update the Web Application directory using the appcfg command. I have tried using "./appcfg.sh update ~/Development/PATH_TO_WEB_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY;", but that too resulted in many errors including "Include dispatch.yaml in updates". So, which command should I use to update the Web Application file?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "update the Web Application file"? If you are performing an appcfg update, you need to make sure the directory "contain an app.yaml file and all of the other files required by the app or the module that the app.yaml file defines."

Please read [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments#update) for details.